# remove last specific character if next position is a whitespace

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I am trying to remove last `,` from a column of strings, only if the next position in the string has a whitespace:

```
strings <- data_frame(strings= c('[16, 10, 15, ]',
                       '[18, 17, 20]' ,
                       '[Norway, Chile, ]', 
                       '[SQL, Java]'))

# removin ','
strings$strings <- gsub("$,", "",strings$strings)
```

However the above code returns the same column without any change.

Output:

```
# [16, 10, 15, ]   
# [18, 17, 20]     
# [Norway, Chile, ]
# [SQL, Java]
```

Expected Output:

```
# "[16, 10, 15 ]"  
# "[18, 17, 20]" 
# "[Norway, Chile ]" 
# "[SQL, Java]"
```

How could I change the regex-pattern to get desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sub` as follows:

```r
strings$strings <- sub(",(?=\\s+\\])", "", strings$strings, perl=TRUE)
strings

           strings
1    [16, 10, 15 ]
2     [18, 17, 20]
3 [Norway, Chile ]
4      [SQL, Java]
```

Here is a brief explanation of the regex being used:

```regex
,            match a comma
(?=\\s+\\])  which is followed by one or more whitespace characters,
             which in turn are followed by the closing ]
```

This regex uses a *lookahead* to check for whitespace followed by `]`.  It should be noted that lookaheads assert but do not consume anything, so only the comma actually gets removed.

Answer (score 1):

using capture groups you can do this

```r
strings <- data.frame(strings= c('[16, 10, 15, ]',
                                 '[18, 17, 20]' ,
                                 '[Norway, Chile, ]', 
                                 '[SQL, Java]'))


gsub('(\\,)(\\s\\])', '\\2', strings$strings)
#> [1] "[16, 10, 15 ]"    "[18, 17, 20]"     "[Norway, Chile ]" "[SQL, Java]"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>